# jQuery – Perform function in same div as function caller

Tags: jquery

I am really new to jQuery (and javascript).
I have 2 duplicated "editors" and I want to perform functions on a paragraph contained in the same div as the function caller.

I'm using the `closest` method to find the paragraph but I am not sure it is the best solution. Doing something with the index of the elements would be better?

Also, I'd like to give context to the selector to reduce the amount of DOM traversed.

A simplified version of the markup:

```
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div>
    <p class="paragraph">This is text of box #1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="doBold">Bold</a>
      <a href="#" class="doItalic">Italic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper2">
  <div>
    <p class="paragraph">This is text of box #2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="doBold">Bold</a>
      <a href="#" class="doItalic">Italic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A simplified version of the jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function($){

  var methods = {
    doBold: function () { $(this).closest(':has(.paragraph)').toggleClass('bold') },
    doItalic: function () { $(this).closest(':has(.paragraph)').toggleClass('italic') },
    }

  $('.doBold').click(methods.doBold);
  $('.doItalic').click(methods.doItalic);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var methods = {
        doBold: function(obj) {
            $(obj).parents("div[id*='wrapper']").find('.paragraph').toggleClass('bold');
        },
        doItalic: function(obj) {
            $(obj).parents("div[id*='wrapper']").find('.paragraph').toggleClass('italic');
        },
    }
    $('.doBold').click(function() {
        methods.doBold(this)
    });
    $('.doItalic').click(function() {
        methods.doItalic(this)
    });
});
```

another solution:(that you tried)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var methods = {
        doBold: function(obj) {
            $(obj).closest(":has('.paragraph')").toggleClass('bold');
        },
        doItalic: function(obj) {
            $(obj).closest(":has('.paragraph')").toggleClass('italic');
        },
    }
    $('.doBold').click(function() {
        methods.doBold(this)
    });
    $('.doItalic').click(function() {
        methods.doItalic(this)
    });
});
```

one more solve that apply classes only on paragraph:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var methods = {
        doBold: function(obj) {
            $(obj).closest(":has('.paragraph')").find('.paragraph').toggleClass('bold');
        },
        doItalic: function(obj) {
            $(obj).closest(":has('.paragraph')").find('.paragraph').toggleClass('italic');
        },
    }
    $('.doBold').click(function() {
        methods.doBold(this)
    });
    $('.doItalic').click(function() {
        methods.doItalic(this)
    });
});
```

Comment: @user495915 second solution will apply `bold` and `italic` class for both paragraph and links. if you want to apply only for `paragraph`, then you have to filter. third solution will do filter

Comment: thanks @abdullah.abcoder, it does the trick. Now I have a (maybe silly) question, can I store the part that finds `.paragraph` outside of the methods `doBold` and `doItalic`?

Comment: @user495915 you want to store the whole html of that .paragraph or only text? pls clarify. I may help you

Comment: sorry I was not clear, some concepts are still blurry to me so it is hard to formulate correctly. I was thinking that since a lot of functions will apply to that same paragraph with the `.paragraph` class it could maybe good to have some sort of "shortcut" to the part of the code that finds the correct paragraph and have something like: `doBold: function(obj) {
            myShortCut.toggleClass('bold');
        },`

Comment: user495915 trying but nothing happen.. if successed i will post my answer thanks friend

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "this"

```
 $('doBold').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.paragraph').toggleClass('bold');
 }
```

Comment: this won't work as `.doBold` is not a child of `.paragraph`. My mistake, the html markup was not well formed (I just edited it to be more clear).

Comment: ah - sorry - i should have read more closely! abdullah has it right for you now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this looks fine to me,
the only thing i might have changed, is either give ID's to the editors (Editor1,Editor2) paragraphs, and reference them directry `$("#Editor1")...`
or `$(this).closest('p')...`